# Recorrer string con bucle for y contar las palabras, dudas, Java

Tags: java

Estoy atascado en un ejercicio que consiste en contar las palabras de una cadena teniendo en cuenta que pueden haber varios espacios al principio, al final y entre palabras. No se puede usar el método trim para eliminar espacios ni se puede hacer por medio de tokens.

Lo que he hecho ha sido contar los espacios entre palabras (si hay dos o mas espacios juntos que los cuente como uno) para asi saber el número de palabras que hay.
El problema es que no sé cómo hacer para que no cuente los espacios del principio y final de la cadena.

Esto es lo que tengo por el momento:

```
    
    String texto;
    int x=1;
    
    
    
    texto=sc.nextLine();
    
    for (int i=0;i<texto.length();i++)
            if (texto.charAt(i) == ' ' && texto.charAt(i+1) != ' ')
                x++;
            
            
    System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: Hola! Pregunta: ¿por qué revisas el carácter siguiente además del actual? ¿Está claro que eso va a fallar cuando `i == length-1` porque te vas a salir?

Comment: no necesitas usar el operador lógico &&, basta con esto texto.charAt(i) == ' ' ya que eventualmente tu ciclo recorrerá toda la cadena comparando los espacio existentes ,eso si x debe iniciar en 0

Comment: Este es el típico caso donde se puede usar `i+=2` en vez de `i++` para el valor del *stepping*

Comment: Debes convertir 2 espacios en 1 solo, para esto tienes que ocupar un texto auxiliar para guardar en nuevo string convertido, un while y un for dentro del while. El for lo recorres de 2 en 2 (i+=2) y cuando hay 2 espacios, guardas el nuevo string en el texto auxiliar, una vez terminado el while te vuelve a obligar a buscar otros par de espacion. Si no encuentras un par de espacios detetienes el while. Con esto tienes un texto con solo un espacio. Luego para ver si hay espacio al principio y al final haces 2 if con textoAux[0] y textoAux[textoAux.lenght-1] == " "

Comment: O podrías almacenar los índices de cada espacio y concluir en base a simples matemáticas. Saludos